# NXT clone paramiters

Tags: nxt, nxt-data-cloud, nxt-monetary-system

Hi am looking at creating a currency using NXT creation generator and have been looking for parts in the code to modify and test, this is more of a learning experience for myself.

Is there a way to change certain paramiters

1. Blocksize to increase it?
2. Block timing can this be increased either along side blocksize or separately?
3. Datacloud can this size be increased to upload larger files and also can it be changed so these are permenatly uploaded or put up and only removed when required by the person that uploaded them ?
4. Fees such as uploads, currency creation, asset creation can these be modified increase or decreased there base and max ?

I will probly have more questions, but I am looking were to find to modify these 
appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a way to change anything. But you must carefully think over the changes you do. The source code is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/Jelurida/nxt/src). Here are some directions:

> Blocksize to increase it?

Change the `MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRANSACTIONS` constant

> Block timing can this be increased either along side blocksize or separately?

It can be increased or decreased separately from the block size. In Nxt there is no constant for that. Easiest thing to do is to see how the `BLOCK_TIME` constant is used in Ardor and do the same in Nxt

> Datacloud can this size be increased to upload larger files and also can it be changed so these are permenatly uploaded or put up and only removed when required by the person that uploaded them ?

The size can be changed - `MAX_TAGGED_DATA_DATA_LENGTH`. You cannot delete data which is already announced to the network. You simply cannot force someone to forget some data. If you find a way to do this, please tell me, we will solve the double spend problem in truly scalable way :)

> Fees such as uploads, currency creation, asset creation can these be modified increase or decreased there base and max ?

They can. Search for the implementations of the `nxt.Fee` interface

Comment: Thanks for the feed back mate appreciate it , wish there was a way to direct message if there is im new here so not sure on it

Comment: Maybe slack - https://nxtplatform.org/slack/ ?

Comment: Thanks mate yes im on there ill see if I can connect there with you